# creating a custom JSP tag

Tags: jsp-tags

I'm trying to create a custom JSP tag that would take an array object and display the elements of the tag in an HTML table. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You probably need to make the question more specific. Do you need to know how to make custom tags or how to manipulate the array to create the HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phill mentioned, the Display Tag taglib is very good for this, but it's actually really easy to do using JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
.
.
.
<table summary="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Property 1</th>
      <th>Property 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${someArrayObject}">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${item.property1}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${item.property2}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Depending on your needs, a custom taglib may be overkill.

Comment: Yea..It works but I wanted it without using the JSTL, yea got it now.. Thanks for ur kind sugestion. 

regards, 
Vinayak

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [displayTag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/)? That can form tables out of lists of objects.

Comment: Yea exactly.. but I dont want to add the display display.jar to my application I want to create it by my own.. yea got it now.. 

Thanks for ur kind sugestion.

regards,
Vinayak